# How to inject CSS in modern SharePoint pages using Extensions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx-extensions, modern-pages, cdn

I've followed step-by-step this article on how to inject CSS in modern SharePoint pages using Extensions:

https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

Everything works perfectly in localhost but not when using CDN. The css is apparently just ignored.

This is the code that I am using in my OnInit method:

```
    const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;

    if (cssUrl) {
        // inject the style sheet
        const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
        let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
        customStyle.href = cssUrl;
        customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        customStyle.type = "text/css";
        head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
    }
```

My goal is to inject this css to hide the left-side navigation and place the search on top of the page.

```
nav[role='navigation'] {
    display: none !important;
}
div[class^='searchBox_'] {
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    top: 20px;
}
div[class^='pageContainer_'] {
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

Again, in localhost it works great. Well, not perfect because there is a delay fot the changes to occur, especially in the first access. But I can live with that.

when using --ship things don't work.

Is there an alternative way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below ready-made **SPFx modern script editor** web part.

Steps to deploy:

1. Clone or Download the webpart from [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)
2. Edit the Write-manifests.json.
3. Build the package
4. Build the package and deploy

For details steps refer to the below article :

[Add The Script Editor Webpart back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative**

This sample was just added to sp-dev-fx-webparts: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-add-js-css-ref

It lets you add JS and CSS references on Modern Pages via SPFx application customizer extension.

---

For your own solution to work, make sure that all the steps under **Deploying to your production tenant** has been followed.

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could select 2 answers as correct